# Best (fastest) way to generate ~billion VIN's in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to generate ~billion VIN numbers very-very fast ( < 1hour )?

Now I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO vins (number)
SELECT p.number FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(1,10000000) AS num, 
           upper(substring(md5(random()::text) from 0 for 16)) AS number
    ) p
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

This method is very slow. Besides, it generate only small part of data and need to be manually rerun.

Any ideas?

Comment: It will get much faster if you remove all indexes and constraints from the table first (recreate them afterwards). Besides, entering a billion rows will *always* be time consuming.

Comment: Thanks! Goog hint about indexes & constraints.

Comment: Is your hardware capable of loading a billion rows in less than an hour?

Comment: I don't thing so. Maybe if I will manage this database only with hard limited queries - than yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to dropping indexes and constraints as suggested by @Laurenz Albe set the table `unlogged` while inserting.

Storing the vin number as bytea cuts its size by more than half making it faster both for inserting and searching

```
create table vins (number bytea primary key);

alter table vins set unlogged;

explain analyze
insert into vins (number)
select decode(left(md5(random()::text),16), 'hex')
from generate_series(1,10000000) s 
on conflict do nothing;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on vins  (cost=0.00..37.50 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=246576.200..246576.200 rows=0 loops=1)
   Conflict Resolution: NOTHING
   Tuples Inserted: 9976941
   Conflicting Tuples: 23059
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series s  (cost=0.00..27.50 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=1633.756..56257.494 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.097 ms
 Execution time: 246661.084 ms
```

Turn logging back on:

```
alter table vins set logged;
```

To search:

```
select
    encode(number, 'hex') hex_representation,
    pg_column_size(number) bytea_storage_size,
    pg_column_size(encode(number, 'hex')) text_storage_size
from vins
where number = decode('987ce0e63614afbb', 'hex')
;
 hex_representation | bytea_storage_size | text_storage_size 
--------------------+--------------------+-------------------
 987ce0e63614afbb   |                  9 |                20
```